# Configure masscan to leave user agent in server logs

Tags: logs, kali-linux, nmap, scanner

I'm trying to configure the nmap-like program masscan to leave a useragent (and all the other usual info that comes along with the useragent, but the useragent is what I'm most concerned with) in the server logs of every port it scans, which I know it can do, because that's how I found it initially. However, when I scan my test server, masscan doesn't leave any trace of having scanned it... (well, I'm sure it does, but not in my express server log). This is the case whether or not I change the user agent description.

Does anyone know how to configure it so it actually leaves this information in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

By default, masscan doesn't issue a HTTP request so it won't leave any traces in http server logs. If you want to send a HTTP request, use the `--banners` argument. This will use the default user agent. If you want to customise it, use the `--http-user-agent` argument.